# Adding two navigation menus on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site isn't picking up both of my menus from my functions.php file. I've tried many ways but always seems to just pick up my footer menu (displaying in as my header menu and footer). I've created one for the header menu and one for the footer menu.

Where is it likely ive gone wrong?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure your question contains enough information about what you have done (code excerpts please) and what you have tried in terms of trouble shooting.

Comment: add_theme_support( 'menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ),
      'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' )      
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );